# Pyspark dataframe: How to randomly drop one row if there are two duplicated rows for the same primary key? Databricks

Tags: python, database, dataframe, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm working in Azure databricks, pyspark
There is now an existing dataframe like below

df:

| id | Name | Age | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | 18 | USA |
| 2 | Lily | 25 | Japan |
| 2 | Lily | 22 | Japan |
| 3 | John | 23 | China |
| 4 | Snow | 36 | Korea |
| 5 | Tom | 28 | Austria |
| 5 | Cindy | 28 | Italy |

column "id" is the primary key and cannot have duplicated values, which means all the numbers should appear only once, but now as you could see, number 2 and 5 have two rows with different values.
I need to keep only one row for id 2 and one row for id 5 only. We can drop randomly and keep the other row, or we can keep only the upper row if there are duplicated rows

I need to have the following:

| id | Name | Age | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | 18 | USA |
| 2 | Lily | 25 | Japan |
| 3 | John | 23 | China |
| 4 | Snow | 36 | Korea |
| 5 | Tom | 28 | Austria |

or below is also fine:

| id | Name | Age | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | 18 | USA |
| 2 | Lily | 22 | Japan |
| 3 | John | 23 | China |
| 4 | Snow | 36 | Korea |
| 5 | Cindy | 28 | Italy |

How should I write the scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: which databricks are you using. Azure, aws or community?

Comment: Azure Databricks

Comment: you could just use `dropDuplicates()` with a subset column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could simply use [`dropDuplicates()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates.html#pyspark-sql-dataframe-dropduplicates) with `id` as subset column.

see below example

```py
# given the following input
# +---+---+---+---+
# | id| c1| c2| c3|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  1|foo|bar|baz|
# |  1|foo|baz|bar|
# |  2|foo|bar|baz|
# |  2|foo|bar|baz|
# +---+---+---+---+

data_sdf. \
    dropDuplicates(subset=['id']). \
    show()

# +---+---+---+---+
# | id| c1| c2| c3|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  1|foo|bar|baz|
# |  2|foo|bar|baz|
# +---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach to remove duplicate records is to add a row number column to the dataframe for each `id`  group and then keep only the first row for each group.

**Code:**

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
# Define the schema for the dataframe
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Age", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Country", StringType(), True)
])

# Create the dataframe
data = [
    (1, "Mike", 18, "USA"),
    (2, "Lily", 25, "Japan"),
    (2, "Lily", 22, "Japan"),
    (3, "John", 23, "China"),
    (4, "Snow", 36, "Korea"),
    (5, "Tom", 28, "Austria"),
    (5, "Cindy", 28, "Italy")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

# Show the dataframe
df.show()

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
# Define a window function to partition by id and order by any column
window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("Name")

# Add a row number column to the dataframe
df = df.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(window))

# Keep only the first row for each id
df = df.filter(df.row_number == 1).drop("row_number")

# Show the resulting dataframe
df.show()
```

- `Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("Name")`: This defines a window function that partitions the dataframe by the  `id`  column and orders the rows within each partition by the  `Name`  column.
- `df.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(window))`: This adds a new column called  `row_number`  to the dataframe, which contains the row number for each partition defined by the window function.
- `df.filter(df.row_number == 1).drop("row_number")`: This filters the dataframe to keep only the rows where the  `row_number`  column is equal to 1, which corresponds to the first row within each partition. It then drops the  `row_number`  column from the resulting dataframe.

**Output:**

| id | Name | Age | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | 18 | USA |
| 2 | Lily | 25 | Japan |
| 3 | John | 23 | China |
| 4 | Snow | 36 | Korea |
| 5 | Cindy | 28 | Italy |

[image]